# iphone, how to create Combobox like in this image (Birthday combo box)

Tags: iphone, combobox

How can i display combo box like the one you see in the image (Birthday combobox) on this site:
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-use-picker-in-iphone/

Is it UITextField or UIButton... How can i create such control?

Comment: Read the article you are linking

Comment: I've read that... But that article is not implementing the interface which is shown in this image

Comment: Are you referring to the view above the date picker?

Comment: @Bourne, Yeah above date picker, namely Birthday combo box, next to 'Event' label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a custom button with image that looks like combobox. pressing it opens probably a date picker. You need an image that looks like combobox and to customize your table cell appearance - add a button as accessory view or create a custom cell in IB

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the screenshot at the top of the article ?

To me it looks like the app is either a WebView or has manually created button image ... to my knowledge there is no native Combo buttons in the UIKit.

Sorry to share the bad news.
Good Luck

Comment: Thank u so much @Nava, @MDMonty
Yeah  i know there is no such UIControl available in UIKit. Let me create a custom button and add an image in it